# Passing multiple navparam in ionic 2 from html

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2, ionic3

Hello I want to pass multiple data is their any way like

```
<button [navPush]="mainPage" [navParams]='data1+data2">Main Page </button>
```

Please help
thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can easily use an object with array:

```
<button [navPush]="mainPage" [navParams]='{data:[data1,data2]}">Main Page </button>
```

then access it like this:

```
navParams.get('data');
```

You can also set it like this:

```
<button [navPush]="mainPage" [navParams]='{data1:data1,data2:data2]}">Main Page </button>
```

And access them like:

```
navParams.get('data1');
```

Answer (score 2):

Since what you send in `navParam` is an object, so you can put there all the data:

```
import { MainPage } from './main';

@Component({
  ...
})
class MyPage {
  mainPage: any;
  params: Object;

  constructor(){
    this.mainPage = MainPage;
    this.params = { data1: 'foo', data2: 'bar' };
  }
}
```

And then use it in the view:

```
<button ion-button [navPush]="mainPage" [navParams]="params">Go</button>
```

Then you can get that information like this:

```
let data1 = navParams.get('data1'); // foo
let data2 = navParams.get('data2'); // bar
```

Even though you can define the object in the template just like you can see in @Yamin's answer, it's recommended to define it in the component code.